# How to use phantomjs to download the html code of an xmlFile with an xslFile?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt, phantomjs

I want to get the html code of a xml file with a xslFile.But when I use phantomjs to get the code ,I find it is the xml code but not the html code.An Interesting thing is that When I  view the elements in the FireFox Webbrowser ,it is the html code I see.But I get the xml code with phantomjs.

[code in fireFox webbrowser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwbaG.png)

but it is xml code in the cmdLine with phantomjs.Look here:

[code I get in the cmdLine with phantomjs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3HnM.png)

Here coms the question,how can I get the html code of an xml with an xsl File?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you open it in Chrome/Safari/Opera/Vivaldi?

Comment: It is the same to the FF.

Comment: I don't know why it is xml code but not html code ,via phantomjs.But in the webBrowser it is html code .(I use xsl to decorate the xml file.)

Comment: Perhaps PhantomJS simply doesn't support it as part of a page load.

Comment: It does look like PhantomJS doesn't support XSLT as part of a page load, but perhaps it does support JS-based XSLT. You can try it yourself.

Comment: I get the magicXML to get what I want to do.Thanks!